# Sticky Column in MUI data grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I want to make a column sticky in Mui x data grid. I know there is an option to do that in the pro version, but I want to use the community version and was wondering whether this can be achieved by overriding the original css.

I've tried a lot of things but none of them worked.

Comment: Well were you able to achieve it, if so would you mind sharing the solution? I have been looking for the same.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution. I am also looking for the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in community version too.

Here, is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-forked-y9pfwr?file=/src/App.tsx

If this is not the answer you're looking for, please share your code with us, So we can assist you further.

Comment: This just makes the Column header sticky... I want a single column along with all its values to be sticky

Comment: This would only make the column header sticky. The question is for making the entire column sticky